# Can't access any page other than my homepage in apache server

Tags: angular, apache, .htaccess

I have created a small Angular application that runs perfectly on localhost, but I can't make it work correctly on my server.
Anytime I try to load any other url than the homepage/base url, I get either an error 403 or 404 depending on the solutions I tried.

This is an apache server running on Centos7, with the following VHosts
(sensitive data (domain url, app name) redacted) :

VHost to redirect http to https :

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName domain_url
    ServerAlias domain_url (without www.)
    DocumentRoot /var/www/MyApp/html
    ErrorLog /var/www/MyApp/log/error.log
    CustomLog /var/www/MyApp/log/requests.log combined
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} = domain_url [OR]
RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} = domain_url (without www.) 
RewriteRule ^ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [END,NE,R=permanent]
</VirtualHost>
```

HTTPS VHost :

```
<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerName domain_url
    ServerAlias domain_url (without www.)
    DocumentRoot /var/www/MyApp/html
    ErrorLog /var/www/MyApp/log/error.log
    CustomLog /var/www/MyApp/log/requests.log combined

    <Directory /var/www/MyApp/>
        AllowOverride All
    </Directory>

Include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-apache.conf
SSLCertificateFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/domain_url/cert.pem
SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/domain_url/privkey.pem
SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/domain_url/chain.pem
</VirtualHost>
</IfModule>
```

Some of the relevant parts of the httpd.conf file :

```
<Directory />
    AllowOverride none
    Require all denied
</Directory>

DocumentRoot "/var/www/html"

<Directory "/var/www">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
</Directory>

<Directory "/var/www/html">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
</Directory>

<Directory "/var/www/MyApp">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

When I run my website with only these files, the Homepage runs perfectly, and navigation within my angular app works, but trying to load any url other than "www.domain.com/" (for exemple : "www.domain.com/about") returns an Error 404 Not Found.

I then added the following .htaccess file in 'var/www/MyApp/html' (mostly generated from an online htaccess generator, I only added a Require all granted and I don't even know if it's useful, I'm very new to apache configuration) :

```
Require all granted

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On

  # Redirection of requests to index.html
  RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI} -f [OR]
  RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI} -d
  RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
  # Redirect all non-file routes to index.html
  RewriteRule ^(?!.*\.).*$ index.html [NC,L]
</IfModule>

# Disable browser caching for all files that don't get a hash string by Angular.
<FilesMatch "^(?!.*\.([0-9a-z]{20})\.).*$">
  <IfModule mod_headers.c>
    FileETag None
    Header unset ETag
    Header unset Pragma
    Header unset Cache-Control
    Header unset Last-Modified
    Header set Pragma "no-cache"
    Header set Cache-Control "max-age=0, no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate"
    Header set Expires "Mon, 1 Jan 1900 00:00:00 GMT"
  </IfModule>

</FilesMatch>
```

After adding this .htaccess, I now get an error 403 Forbidden whenever I try to load anything including my homepage.

I'm completely lost on what I did wrong and can't seem to find any solution on the web so any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Ok I finally found a solution that works for me :

I replaced the first half of my htaccess file to the following (and got rid of the Require all granted) :

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteRule ^index\.html$ - [L]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule . /index.html [L]
</IfModule>
```

And it finally seems to work, Apache doesn't fire 403 or 404 errors anymore !

Answer (score 0):

You need to configure rewrite rules with fallback to the index file

[Angular's official docs](https://angular.io/guide/deployment#server-configuration) have examples on how to do it for mainstream web servers.

tl;dr;

In your `.htaccess` you need rules that implement fallback to the index file:

```
  RewriteEngine On 
  # If an existing asset or directory is requested go to it as it is 
  RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI} -f [OR] 
  RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI} -d 
  RewriteRule ^ - [L] 
 
  # If the requested resource doesn't exist, use index.html 
  RewriteRule ^ /index.html
```